# Divs not taking up full page height in Safari for iPhone & iPad

Tags: mobile-safari, mobile-website, mobile-webkit

I've been having trouble getting my page elements to fill up 100% of the viewport height in mobile Safari (iPhone and iPad). I have an element which contains my page elements set to 100% height (as well as the HTML and Body being set to 100% height) and this DOES fill 100% of the viewport height.

The problem is the 3 child elements of the container (.main-header:10%, .main-content:80% and .main-footer:10%) which add up to 100% height still have a small (approx. 2px) gap at the bottom of the page where I can see the background of the parent (.page) element.

If anyone else has experienced and fixed this issue I'd be extremely grateful for any help.

Thanks!

You can see my stripped-down HTML/CSS on this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Rockstar79/zpTtF/

Here's the full code with meta tags etc:

CSS

```
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

div {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,
p {
    font-size: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.page {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.main-header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    position: relative;
}

.main-content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
    position: relative;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.main-footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    position: relative;
}

.main-header,
.main-footer {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Plain Mobile Test</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page" id="page-1">
        <div class="main-header">
            <h1>Header</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="main-content">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet sunt aut libero sequi distinctio molestias nulla quidem fugiat. Maxime voluptates.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="main-footer">
            <h3>Footer</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```